# git add . , where these files stored?

Tags: git, github

I am learning git basics. I have some confusion on understanding of the following.

If add files to git as `git add <filename(s)>`, will it add them in the `.git/index` or somewhere else? How git knows some files added (tracked or untracked etc.)? From where it will fetch that info (prior to commit)?

When `git commit` or git add , `.git/index` file size is increasing.

Can do we call `.git/index` as the git local repository? or is it the main DB for git?

`.git/HEAD` only points to the current branch or does it store the files after commit?

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: These are git internals--implementation details.

Comment: This free online Git book will answer many of your questions https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 - see chapter 10

Answer (score 2):

If you add a file to Git, it will create a blob of that file in the .git/objects directory. Additionally, an entry in the .git/index file will be created with the path of the file, permissions and the hash of the blob. The reason why the index file size is not increasing, could be that it already had an entry for that file, or it had another entry which became obsolete and replaced by the new entry.

.git/index is the Git index, .git is the local repository. HEAD is only a reference, as you already noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Git has a staging area (also known as: stash, index, cache depends on your git version)

[image]

When you are adding file(s) you simply tell git to tart track them from this point on. Once You add them git calculate the SHA-1 of the files and they are stored under your `.git/object` folder in a specials format (TYPE LENGTH + content - in zip)

Very useful information on the whole proceess can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

Comment: The staging area and the stash are different things. Also, the staging area is referred to as index or cache (mostly in command line options) even within the same Git version, unfortunately.

Comment: The index used to be called stash in the past (very long ago)